# Error with installing browsersync for node js through command prompt

Tags: node.js, cmd, npm, browser-sync

A little background: I have a Windows 10 laptop with 8.3 gigs of usable space(6.3 gigs are python, so 2 gigs of usable space), so I install and download everything onto an external hard drive. Unfortunately, my previous external hard drive started malfunctioning and physically falling apart after less than 6 months, so I've been in the process of moving files and reinstalling programs to my new hard drive. Recently I joined a MOOC that asked me to download Node JS and install browsersync on it.

I installed Node JS and tested it and npm with -version, and both were installed. I closed and reopened the cmd. However, when I ran npm install -g browser-sync it gave me the following: [cmd errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E7xgQ.png)
The first error is due to a typo, but the second error is the real one.

Here is the true error in text:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.10240]
C:\Users\Bracklinn>npm install -g -browser-sync
npm ERR! addLocal Could not install C:\Users\Bracklinn
npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.10240
npm ERR! argv "D:\\Programs\\NodeJs\\node.exe" "D:\\Programs\\NodeJs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "-browser-sync"
npm ERR! node v4.4.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.8
npm ERR! code EISDIR
npm ERR! errno -4068
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! eisdir EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read
npm ERR! eisdir This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! eisdir and is related to npm not being able to find a package.json in
npm ERR! eisdir a package you are trying to install.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Bracklinn\npm-debug.log
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling, googled it a bunch of times, and just ended up wasting 2 hours. I think it has something to do with my cmd is in my computer drive but node.js is on my hard drive. So I've turned here for help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sorry, the image I put up has a typo. I changed it to be correct.

Comment: It isn't `-browser-sync` nor `brower-sync`. It should be `browser-sync`. In fact the actual URL for browser-sync is https://registry.npmjs.org/browser-sync. Make sure you you can fetch this url from command line.